# El select queda abierto cuando tomo una screenshot con html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

Estoy tomando una captura con la libreria html2canvas pero al momento de tomarla las opciones del select quedan desplegadas en la captura.

Este es mi js de como tomo la captura:

```js
function capture(){
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas){

        var solicitud = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
        var nombreM = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", "save-any.php", true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        ajax.send("image=" + canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.9) + "&soli=" + solicitud  + "&name=" + nombreM);


        
        swal({
            title: "",
            text: "Su solicitud se ha registrado correctamente " + solicitud,
            icon: "success",
            value: "confirm",
            buttons: {
                confirm: "Confirmar"
            }
        }).then((confirm) =>{
            if(confirm){
                location.reload();
            }
        });
        
    });
}
```

Este es el select que se abren las opciones cuando tomo la screenshot:

```html
<select name="day" style="width: 275px;" multiple class="chosen-select" id="select0" data-placeholder="Seleccione los días a faltar">
         <option value="7">Lunes</option>
         <option value="8">Martes</option>
         <option value="9">Miercoles</option>
         <option value="10">Jueves</option>
         <option value="10">Viernes</option>
</select>
```

El select se esta llamando con una libreria, así la estoy llamando:

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu pregunta pero el select se queda abierto por la propiedad "multiple" si quieres que solo se vea como una lista desplegable solo retira el multiple

```html
<select name="day" style="width: 275px;" class="chosen-select" id="select0" data-placeholder="Seleccione los días a faltar">
         <option value="7">Lunes</option>
         <option value="8">Martes</option>
         <option value="9">Miercoles</option>
         <option value="10">Jueves</option>
         <option value="10">Viernes</option>
</select>
```

O igual con css podrías hacerlo desplegable o intentar hacer algo como:

```js
  $(function() {
                $('#MultipleCheckboxes').multiselect({
                    enableClickableOptGroups: true,
                    includeSelectAllOption:true,
                    nonSelectedText: 'Seleccionar días'
                });
            });
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
  
  
    <select id="MultipleCheckboxes" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="7">Lunes</option>
         <option value="8">Martes</option>
         <option value="9">Miercoles</option>
         <option value="10">Jueves</option>
         <option value="10">Viernes</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: perdón por no ser lo bastante claro, el select se despliega normal y se selcciona los días, pero cuando tomo la captura con la libreria el select queda abierto como para seleccionar más, espero ahora haber sido claro

Comment: lo que digo es que no se si sea por error de la propia libreria o que, pero solo quiero tomar la captura de todo lo que hay pero sin que ese select abra las opciones solo se muestre lo que el selecciono